# Why does the page reload when the button is pressed

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a input text field with datalist. The Datalist data comes from a database. The input field is generated dynamically with javascript and if i transfer the value of the input field into the textarea field with the button, the page is reloading and I don't know why.

If someone could help me, that would pretty nice :)

This is the snippet of the button in line 10:

```
<button class="button3" style="width:185px;" onclick="artikeleinfuegen()">Artikel &uuml;bernehmen</button>
```

And this is the function:

```
function artikeleinfuegen() {
var x = document.getElementById("artikelsuche").value;
document.getElementById("artikelbeschreibung[]").innerHTML = x;
}
```

This is the whole script.

```
var steuer = '19,00';

function O(id) {
return document.getElementById(id)
}

function insertPos() {
pos = '<table><tr>';
pos += '<td valign=top style="width:100px;"><input type=text name="anz[]" value="1" size=4     onKeyUp="calculate()" /></td>';
pos += '<td valign=top style="width:100px;"><select name="einheit[]"><option value="Lfm.">Lfm.</option><option value="Pal.">Pal.</option><option value="pschl.">pschl.</option><option value="Pkg.">Pkg.</option><option value="Std.">Std.</option><option value="Stk.">Stk.</option> size=4 onKeyUp="calculate()" /></td>';
pos += '<td valign=top><input type="text" list="artikelliste" name="artikelsuche" id="artikelsuche" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Artikelsuche" style="width:700px;"><button class="button3" style="width:185px;" onclick="artikeleinfuegen()">Artikel &uuml;bernehmen</button><br><textarea style="width:900px;" rows=7 name=dsc[] id=artikelbeschreibung[] onKeyUp="typeAhead(event, this)"></textarea></td>';
pos += '<td valign=top style="width:100px;"><input type=text name="ep[]" value="" size=4 onKeyUp="calculate()" /></td>';
pos += '<td valign=top style="width:100px;"><input type=text name="poserab[]" value="0" size=4 onKeyUp="calculate()" /></td>';
pos += '<td valign=top style="width:100px;"><input type=text name="posprab[]" value="1" size=4 onKeyUp="calculate()" /></td>';
pos += '<td valign=top><input style="color:red;" type=button name="del[]" value=" X " onclick="deletePos(this);"/></td>';
pos += '</tr></table>';
obj = document.createElement("DIV");
obj.innerHTML = pos;
O("docpos").appendChild(obj);
a_anz = document.getElementsByName("anz[]");
a_anz[a_anz.length - 1].focus()
}

function Rabatt() {
return '<div class="column1">Gesamtrabatt &euro;<input type=text name="geserab" value="0" size=4 onKeyUp="calculate()"></div><div class="column1">Gesamtrabatt %<input type=text name="gesprab" value="1" size=4 onKeyUp="calculate()"></div>';
}

function deletePos(obj) {
O("docpos").removeChild(obj.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);
calculate()
}

function calculate() {
a_anz = document.getElementsByName("anz[]");
a_ep = document.getElementsByName("ep[]");
a_poserab = document.getElementsByName("poserab[]");
a_posprab = document.getElementsByName("posprab[]");
b_geserab = document.getElementsByName("geserab");
b_gesprab = document.getElementsByName("gesprab");
sum = 0;
for (f = 0; f < a_anz.length; f++) {
    menge = parseFloat(a_anz[f].value.replace(/,/, "."));
    preis = parseFloat(a_ep[f].value.replace(/,/, "."));
    postenrabatteuro = parseFloat(a_poserab[f].value.replace(/,/, "."));
    postenrabattprozent = parseFloat(a_posprab[f].value.replace(/,/, "."));
    if (!(isNaN(menge) || isNaN(preis))) sum = sum + (((menge * preis) - (menge * postenrabatteuro)) * postenrabattprozent)
}
gesamtrabatteuro = parseFloat(b_geserab[0].value.replace(/,/, "."));
gesamtrabattprozent = parseFloat(b_gesprab[0].value.replace(/,/, "."));
mwst = parseFloat(steuer.replace(/,/, "."));
st = sum * mwst / 100;
gr = (sum * gesamtrabattprozent - gesamtrabatteuro) - sum;
nettoabzug = sum + gr;
total = sum + st;
O("netto").value = sum.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\./, ",") + " â‚¬";
O("gr").value = gr.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\./, ",") + " â‚¬";
O("nettoabzug").value = nettoabzug.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\./, ",") + " â‚¬";
O("steuer").value = st.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\./, ",") + " â‚¬";
O("brutto").value = total.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\./, ",") + " â‚¬"
}

function artikeleinfuegen() {
var x = document.getElementById("artikelsuche").value;
document.getElementById("artikelbeschreibung[]").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Edit:

I know that's not the best script you've seen. I'm learning JS & PHP for the last 4 weeks and i doing my best.

This is the whole html / php code

```
<?php
include '../../inc/header.php';
include '../../inc/nav.php';
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/angebot.css" type="text/css">

<style>
textarea { 
width: 100%;
padding: 12px 20px;
margin: 8px 0;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
box-sizing: border-box;

}   
</style>

<script src="../../js/angebot_erstellen.js"></script>

<section>

<h1>Angebot erstellen</h1>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["angebot-erstellen"])){

//Datenbank-Verbindung herstellen
include '../../inc/connect.php';

//Nutzereingabe aus Angebotposition in Variablen speichern
$kunde = $_POST["kunde"];
$anrede = $_POST["anrede"];
$datum = $_POST["datum"];
$referenz = $_POST["referenz"];
$zahlungsbedingungen = $_POST["zahlungsbedingungen"];
$netto = $_POST["netto"];
$mwst = $_POST["mwst"];
$brutto = $_POST["brutto"];
$pos1anz = $_POST['anz'][0];
$pos1einheit = $_POST['einheit'][0];
$pos1dsc = $_POST['dsc'][0];
$pos1ep = $_POST['ep'][0];
$pos1rab = $_POST['posrab'][0];
$pos2anz = $_POST['anz'][1];
$pos2einheit = $_POST['einheit'][1];
$pos2dsc = $_POST['dsc'][1];
$pos2ep = $_POST['ep'][1];
$pos2rab = $_POST['posrab'][1];

// 3. String für SQL-Anweisung erstellen
$insertString = "INSERT INTO angebote (kunde, anrede, datum, referenz, zahlungsbedingungen, netto, mwst, brutto, pos1anz, pos1einheit, pos1dsc, pos1ep, pos1rab, pos2anz, pos2einheit, pos2dsc, pos2ep, pos2rab)
VALUES ('$kunde', '$anrede', '$datum', '$referenz', '$zahlungsbedingungen', '$netto', '$mwst', '$brutto', '$pos1anz', '$pos1einheit', '$pos1dsc', '$pos1ep', '$pos1rab', '$pos2anz', '$pos2einheit', '$pos2dsc', '$pos2ep', '$pos2rab');";

// SQL-Anweisung durchfuehren
$check = mysqli_query($connect, $insertString);

if($check) {
    echo '<span style="color: green;" /><strong>Angebot erfolgreich erstellt</strong></span>';
}}

// Hier wird der Kunde ausgegeben, welcher zuvor ausgewählt wurde.

// Kundenauswahl Verarbeitung
// 1. Verbindung zur Datenbank herstellen
include '../../inc/connect.php';

// 2. Prüfe Radio-Button-Auswahl
if(isset($_GET["auswahl"])){

// 3. Datenbankabfrage starten
$id = $_GET["auswahl"];
$abfrage = "SELECT * FROM kunden WHERE id = $id";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $abfrage);

// 4. Datensatz in Variablen speichern
$kdata = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$firma = $kdata["firma"];
$anrede = $kdata["anrede"];
$vorname = $kdata["vorname"];
$nachname = $kdata["nachname"];
$strasse = $kdata["strasse"];
$plz = $kdata["plz"];
$ort = $kdata["ort"];
}       

// 5. Das Bearbeiten-Formular anzeigen
echo "<form action='angebot_erstellen.php' method='post'>";
echo "<div class='column3'>";
echo "<input name='id' type='hidden' value='$id'>";
echo "<textarea name='kunde' rows='10' cols='30'>$firma\n$vorname $nachname\n$strasse\n$plz $ort</textarea>";
echo "</div>";

// Hier wird die Artikelsuche ausgegeben

// 1. Artikeldaten Abfrage
$abfrageartikelsuche = "select artikelname from artikel";
$resultartikelsuche = mysqli_query($connect, $abfrageartikelsuche) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connect));

?>

<!-- Artikelsuche -->
<datalist id="artikelliste">
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultartikelsuche)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['artikelname']; ?>"><?php echo $row['artikelname']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</datalist>
<?php mysqli_close($connect); ?>

<!-- Obere Eingabemaske -->
<div class="column3">
    <textarea name="anrede" id="anrede" rows="10" cols="30" placeholder="Anrede"/></textarea>
</div>
<div class="column3">
    <input type="date" name="datum" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"/>
    <input type="text" disabled name="angebotid" placeholder="Angebotsnummer (wird automatisch vergeben)"/>
    <input type="text" name="referenz" placeholder="Referenz"/>
</div>

<!-- Hier beginnt die Angebotsbearbeitung fÂŸr Positionen -->
<!-- Positionen -->
<div id="docpos">
<table class="plist" style="font-size:10px;">
<tbody><tr>
<th style="width:100px;">Menge</th>
<th style="width:100px;border-left:1px solid grey;">Einheit</th>
<th style="width:900px;border-left:1px solid grey;">Beschreibung</th>
<th style="width:100px;border-left:1px solid grey;">EP Netto</th>
<th style="width:100px;border-left:1px solid grey;">Pos. Rabatt &euro;</th>
<th style="width:100px;border-left:1px solid grey;">Pos. Rabatt %</th>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
</tbody></table></div>

<input type="button" class="button2" name="newpos" style="float:right; clear:both;margin-right:25px;" value="Position erstellen" onclick="insertPos()">

<div class="column70">
<div class="column50">
<textarea name="zahlungsbedingungen" id="zahlungsbedingungen" rows="10" cols="30" placeholder="Zahlungsbedingungen"></textarea>
</div>  

<div class="column50">
<select name="gesamtrabatt" id="gesamtrabatt">
<option value="Rabatt">Rabatt</option>
<option value="Nachlass">Nachlass</option>
</select>

<div id="rabatt"></div>
<script> document.getElementById("rabatt").innerHTML = Rabatt(); </script>
</div>
<input class="button" type="submit" name="angebot-erstellen" value="Angebot erstellen">

</div>

<div class="column30">
<div style="width:100%;border: #4B9F93 1px solid;border-bottom:2px solid #F39200;"><br>
    <label>&nbsp;Summe Netto:</label><input type="text" name="netto" id="netto" value="" readonly="" style="border:none;background-color:transparent;width:60%;text-align:left;" tabindex="32000"><br>
    <label>&nbsp;Rabatt / Nachlass:</label><input type="text" name="gr" id="gr" value="" readonly="" style="border:none;background-color:transparent;width:60%;text-align:left;" tabindex="32000"><br>
    <label>&nbsp;Summe Netto nach Abzug:</label><input type="text" name="nettoabzug" id="nettoabzug" value="" readonly="" style="border:none;background-color:transparent;width:60%;text-align:left;" tabindex="32000"><br>
    <label>&nbsp;MwSt 19,00%:</label><input type="text" name="mwst" id="steuer" value="" readonly="" style="border:none;background-color:transparent;width:60%;text-align:left;" tabindex="32000"><br>
    <label style="font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;Gesamt Brutto:</label><input type="text" name="brutto" id="brutto" value="" readonly="" style="border:none;background-color:transparent;width:60%;text-align:left;font-weight:bold;" tabindex="32000">
</div>
</div>

</form>
&nbsp;

</section>

<?php
include '../../inc/footer.php';
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it is inside a form, it submits the form. Add `type="button"`

Comment: Your whole script could be refined using templates and proper object navigation

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve] (with proper indendation)

Comment: read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for your feedback. I've also tried type="button", but it still won't work. I will have a look at your other hints. Thanks so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. added code to toggle amounts to JS amouts
2. using the first row of the tbody as template
3. looping over rows when calculating
4. removed all inline event handlers

Note I remove the date PHP  - you can insert that again

I also could not find your typeAhead function. Please replace mine with yours

```js
function typeAhead(e,tgt) { console.log(tgt.value) }; // missing function

const toNum = str => {
  let num = str.replace(/,/, ".");
  return isNaN(num) || num.trim() === "" ? 0 : +num;
}
const toAmount = num => num.toLocaleString('de-DE', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'EUR'
})

const steuer = '19,00';
const mwst = toNum(steuer);
let container, nettoField, grField, nettoabzugField, steuerField, bruttoField, geserabField, gesprabField;


window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  container = document.getElementById("docpos");
  nettoField = document.getElementById("netto");
  grField = document.getElementById("gr");
  nettoabzugField = document.getElementById("nettoabzug");
  steuerField = document.getElementById("steuer");
  bruttoField = document.getElementById("brutto");
  geserabField = document.querySelector("[name=geserab]");
  gesprabField = document.querySelector("[name=gesprab]");

container.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    const parent = tgt.closest("tr");
    if (tgt.classList.contains("button3")) {
      const x = parent.querySelector("[name=artikelsuche]").value;
      parent.querySelector(".artikelbeschreibung").value = x;
    } else if (tgt.classList.contains("del")) {
      tgt.closest("tr").remove();
      calculate()
    }
  })
  container.addEventListener("input", calculate);
  geserabField.addEventListener("input", calculate);
  gesprabField.addEventListener("input", calculate);
  container.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains("artikelbeschreibung")) {
      typeAhead(e, tgt);
    }
  })
  document.querySelector(".button2").addEventListener("click", insertPos);
})


function insertPos() {
  const newTr = container.querySelector("tr").cloneNode(true);
  [...newTr.querySelectorAll("input, textarea")].forEach(inp => inp.value="");
  newTr.querySelector(".anz").value=1;
  container.appendChild(newTr);
  newTr.querySelector(".anz").focus();
}



function calculate() {
  const gesamtrabatteuro = toNum(document.querySelector("[name=geserab]").value);
  const gesamtrabattprozent = toNum(document.querySelector("[name=gesprab]").value);

  let sum = 0;
  [...container.querySelectorAll("tr")].forEach(row => {
    const postenrabatteuro = toNum(row.querySelector(".poserab").value);
    const postenrabattprozent = toNum(row.querySelector(".posprab").value);
    const preis = toNum(row.querySelector(".ep").value);
    const menge = toNum(row.querySelector(".anz").value);
    sum += (((menge * preis) - (menge * postenrabatteuro)) * postenrabattprozent)
  });
  let st = sum * mwst / 100;
  let gr = (sum * gesamtrabattprozent - gesamtrabatteuro) - sum;
  let nettoabzug = sum + gr;
  total = sum + st;

  nettoField.value = toAmount(sum);
  grField.value = toAmount(gr);
  nettoabzugField.value = toAmount(nettoabzug);
  steuerField.value = toAmount(st);
  bruttoField.value = toAmount(total);
}
```

```css
#docpos>tr:first-child .del {
  display: none;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<datalist id="artikelliste">
            <option value="Name1">Name1</option>

</datalist>

<!-- Obere Eingabemaske -->
<div class="column3">
  <textarea name="anrede" id="anrede" rows="10" cols="30" placeholder="Anrede" /></textarea>
</div>
<div class="column3">
  <input type="date" name="datum" value="" />
  <input type="text" disabled name="angebotid" placeholder="Angebotsnummer (wird automatisch vergeben)" />
  <input type="text" name="referenz" placeholder="Referenz" />
</div>

<!-- Hier beginnt die Angebotsbearbeitung für Positionen -->
<!-- Positionen -->
<div>
  <table class="plist" style="font-size:10px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:100px;">Menge</th>
        <th style="width:100px;border-left:1px solid grey;">Einheit</th>
        <th style="width:900px;border-left:1px solid grey;">Beschreibung</th>
        <th style="width:100px;border-left:1px solid grey;">EP Netto</th>
        <th style="width:100px;border-left:1px solid grey;">Pos. Rabatt &euro;</th>
        <th style="width:100px;border-left:1px solid grey;">Pos. Rabatt %</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="docpos">
      <tr>
        <td valign=top style="width:100px;"><input type=text class="anz" name="anz[]" value="1" size="4" /></td>
        <td valign=top style="width:100px;">
          <select name="einheit[]">
            <option value="Lfm.">Lfm.</option>
            <option value="Pal.">Pal.</option>
            <option value="pschl.">pschl.</option>
            <option value="Pkg.">Pkg.</option>
            <option value="Std.">Std.</option>
            <option value="Stk.">Stk.</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td valign=top><input type="text" list="artikelliste" name="artikelsuche" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Artikelsuche" style="width:700px;">
          <button type="button" class="button3" style="width:185px;">Artikel &uuml;bernehmen</button><br>
          <textarea style="width:900px;" rows=7 name=dsc[] class="artikelbeschreibung"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td valign=top style="width:100px;"><input type=text class="ep" name="ep[]" value="" size="4" /></td>
        <td valign=top style="width:100px;"><input type=text class="poserab" name="poserab[]" value="0" size="4" /></td>
        <td valign=top style="width:100px;"><input type=text class="posprab" name="posprab[]" value="1" size="4" /></td>
        <td valign=top><input style="color:red;" type=button class="del" name="del[]" value=" X " /></td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<input type="button" class="button2" name="newpos" style="float:right; clear:both;margin-right:25px;" value="Position erstellen">

<div class="column70">
  <div class="column50">
    <textarea name="zahlungsbedingungen" id="zahlungsbedingungen" rows="10" cols="30" placeholder="Zahlungsbedingungen"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="column50">
    <select name="gesamtrabatt" id="gesamtrabatt">
      <option value="Rabatt">Rabatt</option>
      <option value="Nachlass">Nachlass</option>
    </select>

    <div id="rabatt">
      <div class="column1">Gesamtrabatt &euro;<input type=text name="geserab" value="0" size="4"></div>
      <div class="column1">Gesamtrabatt %<input type=text name="gesprab" value="1" size="4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input class="button" type="submit" name="angebot-erstellen" value="Angebot erstellen">

</div>

<div class="column30">
  <div style="width:100%;border: #4B9F93 1px solid;border-bottom:2px solid #F39200;"><br>
    <label>&nbsp;Summe Netto:</label><input type="text" name="netto" id="netto" value="" readonly="" style="border:none;background-color:transparent;width:60%;text-align:left;" tabindex="32000"><br>
    <label>&nbsp;Rabatt / Nachlass:</label><input type="text" name="gr" id="gr" value="" readonly="" style="border:none;background-color:transparent;width:60%;text-align:left;" tabindex="32000"><br>
    <label>&nbsp;Summe Netto nach Abzug:</label><input type="text" name="nettoabzug" id="nettoabzug" value="" readonly="" style="border:none;background-color:transparent;width:60%;text-align:left;" tabindex="32000"><br>
    <label>&nbsp;MwSt 19,00%:</label><input type="text" name="mwst" id="steuer" value="" readonly="" style="border:none;background-color:transparent;width:60%;text-align:left;" tabindex="32000"><br>
    <label style="font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;Gesamt Brutto:</label><input type="text" name="brutto" id="brutto" value="" readonly="" style="border:none;background-color:transparent;width:60%;text-align:left;font-weight:bold;" tabindex="32000">
  </div>
</div>

</form>
&nbsp;

</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @mplungjan. Nevertheless there is one small thing  When I insert a new position, it always copies the values from the first position too.

Comment: See updated code that empties the fields and puts 1 in anz

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan. Just one last thing. If I select something from the datalist in the input field "artikelsuche" at position 1 i can transfer it to the textarea.

But from position 2 on this does not work anymore.

Comment: You had wrongly used innerHTML instead of value. I changed it

Comment: Oh man. Thank you so much. Is there a way to buy you a coffee? btw. I just noticed that the total discount (geserab & gesprab) does not work if i type something in the input fields.

Comment: @wheezy - can you fix it? Otherwise I'll take a look. What am I supposed to see when I type what? I did not look at the monetary logic, just the wiring so I might have broken something. I prefer a bratwurst to coffee ;)

Comment: I tried to fix this, but I do not understand what `let gr = (sum * gesamtrabattprozent - gesamtrabatteuro) - sum;` means. You multiply by a percentage and take some euro off. But gesamtrabattprozent  is not a percentage unless you type 1.1 for 10%

Comment: I added `geserabField.addEventListener("input", calculate);
  gesprabField.addEventListener("input", calculate);`

Comment: I would like to thank you once again @mplungjan. I have now made some minor changes to the calculation and now everything fits for me. Thank you very much for your efforts.